# Problem with replacing 220v20a outlet for ac . Trips breaker when ac turned on . Breaker 40a

Tags: circuit

220volt20amp outlet trips
40amp double breaker
Proper size wire to use?

Comment: What make and model is the air conditioner in question?

Comment: Is the breaker a "plain" breaker or does it have a TEST button (AFCI and/or GFCI)?

Comment: A 20A outlet does not belong on a 40A breaker, for one thing...

Comment: The wire size (whatever it may currently be) is almost certainly not what's causing the breaker to trip.

Comment: There is some misinformation on this site so be careful. What is the make and model of the outside unit? What is the max breaker size if listed on the outside unit nameplate. A 40 amp breaker is large for a 20 amp unit but code allows larger breakers to be used, 20 amp fla usually tops out at 35 as max breaker on 12 awg wire but it is possible. If the unit was cooling properly it may be a starting capacitor, how old is the unit. We need to know more to help.